# Getting notification on file modification within a container in kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

Purpose: I want to develop a CLI tool that allows file synchronization (when files are modified on either machines) between local machine and a remote machine (container in kubernetes pod).

I wanted to know if there is any way (like event triggered) when someone changes application code by bashing into a running container?

Comment: In most environments I've been in, this is a good way to lose `kubectl exec` access.  Directly editing code in a cluster environment isn't usually a good idea, and this is doubly true in Kubernetes where the cluster can decide to delete and recreate pods pretty freely.  Commit your code to source control, set up a continuous-integration system to build Docker images out of it, and have a controlled deployment process.

Comment: Hey @DavidMaze, thanks for your inputs, we do have this process, the idea I am trying to implement is just for development/testing purposes and not to replace existing CI/CD process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a synced directory with your pod and your local machine
you can create a sidecar container with *sshd* image, mount the same volume to both
containers and then use `sshfs` to mount volume from pod to your machine.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/#creating-a-pod-that-runs-two-containers)
you can find example how to create shared volume.

Next you can use kubectl to portforward trafic to [sshd container](https://hub.docker.com/r/sickp/alpine-sshd/):

```
kubectl port-forward <POD_NAME> 2222:22
```

And then use `sshfs` to mount pod's directory to your machine like this:

```
sshfs root@localhost:/volume my_local_dir -p 2222
```

more info on sshfs you can find [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs)

Although, like somebody already mentioned in comments:

> Directly editing code in a cluster environment isn't usually a good idea [...]

But if you really need to, this is one way to do it.

Let me know if it helped